# what is use of getchildnodes in code given below in android?

Tags: android, domparser, xml

Here is My xml document iam trying to prase it using DOMXmlParser..

```
 < records> 
    <employee>
             <name>Sachin Kumar</name>
             <salary>50000</salary>

    </employee>
    <employee>
            <name>Rahul Kumar</name>
            <salary>60000</salary>
    </employee>
    <employee>
            <name>John Mike</name>
            <salary>70000</salary>
    </employee>
< /records>
```

Following is Code in OnCreate.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();

            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
            Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
            element.normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
            System.out.println("No Of Collected Objects" + nList.getLength() );
            for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nList.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element2 = (Element) node;
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\n\nFirstName : "
                            + getValue("firstname",element2) + "\n");
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\n\nMiddleName : "
                            + getValue("middlename",element2) + "\n");
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\n\nLastName : "
                            + getValue("lastname",element2) + "\n");
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + "Salary : "
                            + getValue("salary",element2) + "\n");
                    tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + "-----------------------");
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell what is the use of getChildNodes in  following code and why the item index should always be 0 ??.

```
    private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
    NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();
    Node node = (Node) nodeList.item(0);
    return node.getNodeValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getChildNotes retrieves a list of all child nodes of the first element with "tag".

Then node is assigned the first element in the returned list.